# How to create, parse and update file using bash script? Is it possible?

Tags: bash, shell, module, scripting, config

Is it possible to write, parse and update any type of file using bash. From anytype mean the file could be a csv, json or other format. Lets say i have detail about website from bash script and i want to write to file, so it looks something like this in bash at near the end of bash script.

```sh
db="MongoDB"
frontend="Angular"
backend="PHP"
```

and i want to write to a file like lets say csv

```
db,MongoDB
frontend,Angular
backend,PHP
```

Later, i should be able to parse that file using bash script so after parsing the `${db}`,`${frontend}`,`${backend}` variables in bash script should be updated from file.Also, if possible i should be able to update any line like when i want to update frontend instead of overwriting i could do `update filename.file frontend data` or something similar. Does anyone have idea how to achieve something similar like  that. It doesnt matter if its external tool or something else but should be able to be achieved in bash.

Edit: So my first bash script collects data from different sources and saves in /root/config.whatevertheformat. Now there are lot of other bash script i have that should parse /root/config.whatevertheformat, then set variables depending on file content. (Optional) I should be able to update that config.whatevertheformat easily like let say there are 50 lines and in line 45 there is data about server (lets say file format is csv) then from bash script i should do something like `update /root/config.csv "server" "nginx"` or similar. Then it goes through each line and updates column 2 of line 45 to "nginx" because first column of line 45 is "server".

Here CSV is just a example for simplicity. If some tool or technique creates, updates and parses json then i dont have problem using that.

Comment: Of course yes text format is easy to use & convert on different format & arrays type variables if needed & so on ; when I learnt unix the prof saif as first `until you need no graphics, all you need is bash, SQL, & network`  this is still true today ...  to take your example : `sed 's/="/,/;s/"$//' toto > titi` create titi as scv from toto as key/value

Comment: well i can create file with lot of work but parsing that file is very difficult, there are multiple bash script that should parse that file to set their variables. So if there was some tool or technique, i would be happy

Comment: Can you explain better you final need because it can impact methods of course ; whould you read the file line to line ?   plain file ; use data in DB ? and so on ....  at least explain your need for example if you need arrays variable temporally line by line reading you can parse file in a while loop

Comment: @francoisP I have explained, could you please help me

Comment: do you mean `update /root/config.csv server "nginx"`  looks for each line if column contains nginx & then act on server (first colomn) in same file ?   if so a while loop to parse file including a test of column 2  to trigger action is your solution ; it is the same if you want to change value nginx on line server  as parameters

Comment: I meant if first column of particular line contain server then it should update the second column of that particular line with nginx. That is updating part. Is there any tool or something else that does that

Answer (score 1):

*I meant if first column of particular line contain server then it should update the second column of that particular line with nginx. That is updating part. Is there any tool or something else that does that*

```
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ line=db
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ change=psql
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ while read ; 
> do 
> sed -i "/$line/ s/,.*$/,$change/" titi
> done < toto
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$ cat titi
db,psql
frontend,Angular
backend,PHP
francois@zaphod:~/tmp/test$
```

as a script it will like like something like

```
#!/bin/bash 
#-ex for debug

file=$1
line=$2
change=$3

#add function to check file exists if so continue

#add function to save file before change

while read ; do 
sed -i.bak "/$2/ s/somethingpattern/$3/" $1  #select line then substitute second part 
done < $1

#add error conditions 

exit 0
```

Comment: How do i parse it, you left the parsing (the most important part)

Comment: just add a dedicated similar loop for parsing (with a variable on read)

Comment: not a single variable on read that is not what i meant, i meant if file contains 100 lines then there should be 100 variables set instead of `while read data` @francoisP instead of writing to single variable.

Comment: So anyidea on how to parse, also you could change your loop from while read to loop entire file

Comment: use a array variable for that you don't need 100 variables a array of 2*100 is just featuring that need

Comment: Well if i use array then i will be confused which part contain which data. Like if 3 index contain server data how would i know 3rd index contain server data? Thats why i need 100 variables. But acutally in my program 10-20 variable suffice